# How to debug Postgres extension?

Tags: windows, postgresql, debugging

I use Visual Studio 2019 to write PostgreSQL extension. I get `dll`, put it in `lib` directory, `.control` and `.sql` files put in `share/extensions` of course. Some functions in extension crash somewhere and pgAmin4 answers me

> Connection to the server has been lost

How can I debug my extension functions?

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with debugging extensions written in C but only on Linux.

The first thing that I do is to add in the code "elog" calls with some DEBUGx level to trace the code in PostgreSQL log. For example to display a character string (for this you also need to run to set `client_min_messages=DEBUG1`):

`elog(DEBUG1,"my_extension: my_function: %s",my_string);`

The second thing is to use gdb debugger that allows to debug a specific backend: on Linux you can attach a running process to gdb with its process id. but I don't know if this is possible with Windows tools.